# How to travel into a list and show it's elements and order position (HASKELL)?

Tags: haskell

I have a list like [1,2,3] and I want to travel by it, show it's items and the order by their position.

A result for the list [1,2,3] would be: [(1,0), (2,1), (3,2)]

I have this code:

```
increase:: Integer -> Integer

increase x = x + 1

firstApear:: [Integer] -> [(Integer, Integer)]

firstApear ls = firstApearAux 0 ls

firstApearAux:: Integer -> [Integer] -> [(Integer, Integer)]

firstApearAux _ [] = []

firstApearAux counter (ls:s) = [(ls, counter)] ++  firstApearAux (increase(counter) s)
```

I'm trying to do it recursively because I don't know other way.

Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't have brackets around `(increase(counter) s)`. The error should say this.

Comment: `zip [1 ..] list`

Answer (score 1):

This line has a problem:

```
firstApearAux counter (ls:s) = [(ls, counter)] ++  firstApearAux (increase(counter) s)
```

You shouldn't have brackets around `increase(counter) s`. This looks to the compiler like you're trying to apply the function `increase` to `counter` and `s`.

In fact, if you look at the error message, it tells you this:

> `main.hs:13:67: error: 
>      • Couldn't match expected type ‘[Integer] -> Integer’
>                    with actual type ‘Integer’
>      • The function ‘increase’ is applied to two arguments,
>         but its type ‘Integer -> Integer’ has only one
>         In the first argument of ‘firstApearAux’, namely
>           ‘(increase (counter) s)’
>         In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
>           ‘firstApearAux (increase (counter) s)’M`

Here's the corrected version. Also, I'm going to clean it up a bit, and get rid of the useless `increase` function. *(Sidenote: `increase` already exists in a far more useful and general form in [`succ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ))*

```
firstApearAux counter (ls:s) = (ls, counter) : firstApearAux (counter + 1) s
```

The rest of your code is fine.